# How to Use context menu with tray icon in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I'm using Netbeans to develop a Java application and I want to create a tray icon at system tray and a popup menu will be display when I right click on tray icon.

I have created a jframe and popup menu by drop and drap them.

But I have a problem.My popup menu have 2 menu items (**Exit** and **Show Login**) but selected menu item is not high-lighted and after I click menu item, popup menu is not closed.

Here is my code:

Declare some global variables

```
SystemTray systemTray = null;
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("D:/key-16x16.png");

TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image);
```

Create and display system tray icon

```
 systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    try
    {
        systemTray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(mainframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Create MouseAdapter and add mouseListener for tray icon

```
MouseAdapter trayIconMouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter()
    {
      //  @Override
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                trayIconMouseClicked(e);
       }
    };

   trayIcon.addMouseListener(trayIconMouseAdapter);
```

handle mouse click event on tray icon. Check whether it is a right click and show popupmenu

```
private void trayIconMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt))
    {
      popupMeunu.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());

    }
}
```

But if i  drap a button to jframe and replace `popupMeunu.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());` by `popupMeunu.show(jButton1, evt.getX(), evt.getY());` everything will be OK.

I don't know why?Pls help me to slove my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add your own MouseListener.

Pass your `popupMeunu` (which needs to be a `java.awt.PopupMenu`, not `javax.swing.JPopupMenu`) in the constructor of `TrayIcon` like that:

```
TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "The Tip Text", popup);
```

I copied this from this [tutorial](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/getting_to_know_system_tray) and it worked fine.